# What is a one-word synonym for "absence of trade"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I am trying to describe the state of an economy (or country/region if you like) that does not trade using a noun.

My best choice so far is "autarky", but this means rather "absence of necessity to trade" than "absence of trade". An economy in autarky does not need to trade and may not trade, yet it could.

Comment: Are you referring to absence of international trade?

Comment: In my case of use, yes. In general, it would not have to be international trade.  For example, the trade could "not happen" between two neighboring villages.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a better one-word solution than autarchy/autarky. If clarity on that necessity point is needed, fall back to the two word solution "closed economy"

Comment: an autarkic economy. Adjective. not: an economy in autarky.

Comment: I would say *autarky* should be spelled *autarchy* in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **isolationist** (as in [**isolationism**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/isolationism)) applies to both politics and economics:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : a policy of national isolation by abstention from alliances and other international political and economic relations

But if you're concerned *only* with economics, your own *autarky* seems like the best fit.

---

That aside, the most direct word is simply [**tradeless**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tradeless):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : having no trade

So, you could say:

> They had a tradeless economy.

---

Something else (which is not a direct fit) would be [**embargo**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embargo):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : a legal prohibition on commerce • a trade *embargo*

As it applies to your situation, you could say:

> They were a completely *embargoed* nation.

Typically, a nation will specifically embargo a few other nations (if not just one), but there's no reason why a particular nation couldn't enforce its own embargo in relation to everybody. (Although I can't think of any instance when this has actually been done.) The word also has a sense of the temporary to it.

Comment: "tradeless" does not work since it's an adjective and "embargo" implies a cause for the absence of trade, which does not hold in my case.

Comment: Verb “institute Isolationism”